# How do I scale down an image without manually editing it?

Tags: support, feature-request

In [this answer](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/2551/14897), the image was scaled down automatically.

Was it done automatically in the past?

Because [this image](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/31388/14897) is way too big.

Comment: For the example you linked, see here: [Resizing an image in a post?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/25051)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is an imgur feature:

The original image:
`https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Mqcu.gif`
[image]

To get the "Medium" scaled version add an "m" to the filename:
`https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Mqcum.gif`
[image]

To get the "Small" scaled version add an "s" to the filename:
`https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Mqcus.gif`
[image]

Note however that if your image is a gif or png with transparency "interesting things" can happen to it in scaling (as illustrated here by the horrible mutilation of the background)

Comment: Large size is also available with `l`, and small size with `t`. The large size is only perhaps 5% smaller than the automatic resizing that the site does. The `l`, `m`, and `t` (thumbnail?) sizes retain the aspect ratio, while the `s` size crops the image to square.